# bind more than one dataGridView to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have MySQL database with four tables, and I've written form an example binding method. But this solution works well only with one table. If I bind more than one, dataGridViews will be filled with info, but Update and Delete commands work badly.

```
 public void Bind(DataGridView dataGridView, string tableName)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        mySqlCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);

        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        mySqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
```

Should I use different mySqlDataAdapter or mySqlCommandBuilder for each new table? I've used different DataTable and BindingSource objects, but when I inserted new row in one table, I had an exception that I left empty field in other table. Any solutions or tips for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wan't to work with a data set? or send a list of tables to this method? how do you want the code to look? what disd you write that didnt work?

Comment: I want to bind all my tables. I'm trying mySqlInterface.Bind(dataGridView1, "Storage"); mySqlInterface.Bind(dataGridView2, "Items"); These two tables are filled with information from database, but update and delete work only on Item table (the last one, I've called bind method).

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never I guess...

I have an application that loads different tables into the same DataGridView  using Visual Studio 2013. So far it is working!

**1. DataTable**

You certainly need to create a new one for each different table you want to load, otherwise you can not clear out the old data. You might think that

```
dataTable.Clear()
```

would do the trick but no, it leaves the old column headers behind so your new table is loaded to the right of all the old columns :-(. Although interestingly if your new table has a column with the same name as the old it merges them!

**2. MySqlAdapter**

I currently create a new one for each table, but at the very least your sql query is changing so you need to create a new SelectCommand:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `" + tableName + "`", conn);
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

I've tried this and it seems to work, but actually it is simpler to just create a new MySqlAdapter and performance really isn't an issue at this point!

**3. SqlCommandBuilder**

Yes you should create a new one because the update and delete commands will be different. I don't use a class variable but create one dynamically (i.e. as a local variable) when I need it.

**4. BindingSource**

I don't believe you need a new BindingSource, but I haven't used them very much so can't be certain.